# Is there a similar Esri "load data tool" on Postgres/PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a remote PostGIS DB and tables with permissions and users, containing data that is being published on GeoServer; and in the office locally, we have an ESRI corporative GDB that is being updated constantly, so now I have to "update" the features on Postgres DB using the updated shape that I export from ESRI GDB.

In ArcCatalog we just erase/delete all the features inside a featureClass and then use the "load" (right click) tool to load all the features from other layers(shape, personal/file/corporative gdb) inside the featureClass. I need to know:

If there's a way to do something similar with QGIS to "load" features from a layer/table inside another layer/table?

Or do the same directly on Postgres tables using PGAdmin?

I shouldn't delete the PostGIS table and use the shape loader since the table is being published and has its own permissions and I think its a mess to "delete and use shapeloader" every time we need to update it.

One option is to open both layers on QGIS and erase all the features in the PostGIS layer and then select and "copy/paste" features from the updated shape but its impossible since QGIS collapsed if you try it with more than (for example) 8.000 features at a time and the layers have ~80.000 features. So doing copy/paste in  "small bites"  is time consuming, like spending a half-day selecting/copy/paste and saving...

Comment: There are many possible solutions that don't involve the awkward procedures you are currently using. I would suggest that you focus the question on one solution (ArcGIS, SQL, QGIS) since the answers are very different.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about all your deleting, and copy/pasting. But in QGIS you have the DBManager plugin for uploading shapefile (and other) layers to PostGIS. And there's the standalone shp2pgsql-gui application (comes with pgAdmin3)

Comment: You can also try OpenGeo Explorer plugin for qGIS. You can import, delete, rename tables, edit fields with that plugin.